# which is faster, using weka gui or implementation weka java code?

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, svm, weka

I'm trying do classification on 2.5 million instances with 41 features using weka , so which do you prefer :

1. using weka GUI
2. write weka implementation java code.

Note that I'm using SVM classification (SMO implementation)

Comment: there should be no difference in training speed.

Comment: i agreed with you but i did some experiment on simple dataset and i found a difference between weka GUI and weka java code in training speed

Comment: do it with Spark ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Weka GUI, more time will be required as GUI gets loaded in memory in addition to Data. So its always better to use commandline methods or invocation through java code.